# Items break container when window width is resized below ~990px

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

[image: site displayed incorrectly in browser tab]

I am not an expert in CSS, but it seems that the issue is in `.container` and `#footer`. I think that since Mi Yodeya (unlike all the other SE sites I checked<sup>1</sup>) is using a repeated image as a background, the `repeat-x` property is repeating enough to fill only its div's width. In this case, it seems that the two offending widths are `100%` and a default `auto`, respectively. Adding a `min-width` property to both seems to fix it.

<sup>1</sup>Upon further investigation, it seems that the current SE beta theme has the same problem.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this in Google Chrome - what version are you using?

Comment: Version 26.0.1410.64 m (current). I reproduced this in Firefox (ver. 20.0.1 and 21.0) and IE10 (ver. 10.0.9200.16540).

Comment: Firefox 18.0.1 on XP: reproduced, in combination with a few levels of ctrl-+, IFF "zoom text only" is unchecked (under View, Zoom).

Comment: Chrome 16.0.912.77 on XP: reproduced; no add-ons or special configuration, just reduce the window width and you'll see it.

Comment: Firefox 20.0 on OS 10.6: reproduced; setting of "zoom text only" doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked with our designer (Jin) - and 1024px is the minimum that we support. While *many* things happen to work at smaller widths, they aren't officially supported to do so. As you notice, it behaves well down to about 990px, which is pretty much the best we can do to make sure nothing looks awful to someone using that width within a window that isn't maximized.

I wasn't able to reproduce it because I initially didn't realize you had the text zoomed to a larger size - thus it didn't break as quickly for me (or at least, it seems that way from your screenshot).

Comment: Fair enough. I just would expect it to shrink to 1024 and then stay there, with the scrollbars being used to navigate the page (as all the other sites do). Btw, I am not using a larger text size, though Monica was.